# Python: Access data from Solr using Pysolr

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

I am using simple Python script to fetch example data from Solr using Pysolr. First I created my core using the following

```
[user@user solr-7.1.0]$ ./bin/solr create -c json_db
WARNING: Using _default configset. Data driven schema functionality is enabled by default, which is
         NOT RECOMMENDED for production use.

         To turn it off:
            curl http://localhost:8983/solr/json_db/config -d '{"set-user-property": {"update.autoCreateFields":"false"}}'

Created new core 'json_db'


[user@user solr-7.1.0]$ ./bin/post -c json_db example/exampledocs/*.json
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/json_db/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file books.json (application/json) to [base]/json/docs
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/json_db/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.398
```

After creating the core I ran simple python script to fetch data

```
from pysolr import Solr

conn = Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/json_db/')
results = conn.search('*:*')
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/APP/application/solr_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    results = conn.search({'*:*'})
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/APP/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 723, in search
    response = self._select(params, handler=search_handler)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/APP/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 421, in _select
    return self._send_request('get', path)
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/APP/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 396, in _send_request
    raise SolrError(error_message % (resp.status_code, solr_message))
pysolr.SolrError: Solr responded with an error (HTTP 404): [Reason: Error 404 Not Found]
```

But when I try to run the query directly from solr I got results like the following[image]

Can somebody guide me what I am doing wrong here ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a more specific search such as conn.search('Monsters')?  Also can you check the value conn and confirm that your connection is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run the script below to fetch the result without using `pysolr` library.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import urllib
import json as simplejson
import pprint
import sys

url = 'give the url here'
wt = "wt=json"
connection = urllib.urlopen(url)

if wt == "wt=json":
  response   = simplejson.load(connection) 
else:
  response   = eval(connection.read())

print "Number of hits: " + str(response['response']['numFound'])
pprint.pprint(response['response']['docs'])
```